# Why won't all three statements print?

Tags: java

We're learning about selections and had to write a program for a rock, paper, scissors game. My program runs with no errors, but it only prints "The computer is ____. You are ____." I can't figure out why it won't print the you win/you lose/it is a draw statement.

```
// Solution for exercise 3.17
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PA6c {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Get user input for number associated with rock, paper, or scissor
    System.out.print("Enter a number 0-2: ");

    int userNumber = input.nextInt();

    // Generate random number for computer
    int compNumber = (int)(Math.random() * 10);

    // Declare rock, paper, and scissor
    int scissor = 0;
    int rock = 1;
    int paper = 2;

    // Determine what the computer is
    if (compNumber == scissor) {
        System.out.print("The computer is scissor. ");
    }
    else if (compNumber == rock) {
        System.out.print("The computer is rock. ");
    }
    else {
        System.out.print("The computer is paper. ");
    }

    // Determine what the user is
    if (userNumber == scissor) {
        System.out.print("You are scissor. ");
    }
    else if (userNumber == rock) {
        System.out.print("You are rock. ");
    }
    else {
        System.out.print("You are paper. ");
    }

    // Determine who won
    if (compNumber == scissor) {
        if (userNumber == scissor) {
            System.out.println("It is a draw.");
        }
        else if (userNumber == rock) {
            System.out.println("You win.");
        }
        else if (userNumber == paper) {
            System.out.println("You lose.");
        }
    }
    else if (compNumber == rock) {
        if (userNumber == scissor) {
            System.out.println("You lose.");
        }
        else if (userNumber == rock) {
            System.out.println("It is a draw.");
        }
        else if (userNumber == paper) {
            System.out.println("You win.");
        }
    }
    else if (compNumber == paper) {
        if (userNumber == scissor) {
            System.out.println("You win.");
        }
        else if (userNumber == rock) {
            System.out.println("You lose.");
        }
        else if (userNumber == paper) {
            System.out.println("It is a draw.");
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `compNumber` must not a 1, 2 or 3. Debug to see what it is.

Comment: It was the compNumber! I changed (Math.random() * 10) to (0 + Math.random() * 2) and it worked properly. Thank you!

Comment: `int compNumber = (int)(Math.random() * 10);` gives you a number `0` to `9`.

Comment: @Mrs.P You're welcome. And you need to learn to debug. This was fairly obvious just looking it over. No offense, just something to focus on. Debugging is a vital skill.

Comment: I will keep that in mind, thank you. This is my first semester taking any programming classes so I'm a super duper beginner lol. My professor recommended I use TextWrangler instead of TextPad (what we use in class) on my Mac and I have no idea how to use a debugger on there.

Comment: @Mrs.P That probably doest even have a debugger, but you don't actually need a debugger to debug simple programs. Place some `System.out.println`s around, and look at the state of the variables. If you're getting a bad result, either there's a logic error, or one of your variables isn't what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with the way you are trying to get Random number. You need your random number to `{0,1,2}` at any point of time but `Math.Random()*10` will give you number in range `{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}`, so your purpose is defeated here. So make sure your `compNumber` will always be one of `{0,1,2}`.

Replace your random number generating line with this,

```
Random rand = new Random();
compNumber = rand.nextInt(0 , 3); // will give you 0 or 1 or 2
```

Comment: Thank you! We haven't used random generation much at all and the only time we did we used the Math.random() * 10, so I guess that's why it's stuck in my head.

Comment: If the answer helps you kindly upvote and accept it as answer, in order to help others.